# $p$th roots of unity in a characteristic $p$ field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, roots-of-unity, abelian-varieties, group-schemes

Let $\mu_n$ denote the group scheme of $n$-th roots of unity over a field $k$. Let $p$ be the characteristic of $k$. I've read that if $(n,p) = 1$, $\mu_n$ is the discrete group isomorphic to the $n$th roots of unity in $k^*$, and if $n = p^m$, then $\mu_n = \operatorname{Spec} k[T]/(T^{p^m}-1)$.

By saying $\mu_n$ is isomorphic to the $n$th roots of unity in $k^*$, does it actually mean the $\overline{k}$-points of $\mu_n$? And it that is true, it seems like the $\overline{k}$ points should be the same thing when $n = p^m$? What makes the $k = p^m$ case more complicated?

Comment: what is a group scheme? What is Spec?

Comment: @uniquesolution these are constructions in algebraic geometry. If you are unfamiliar with them, you should go look them up on your own - this question does not suffer for not explaining those terms.

Comment: @KReiser - Thank you for your answer. I reserve my fundamental right to ask questions whose answers are known to others. I can't locate the point where I said the question suffers from anything.

Comment: @uniquesolution the comments to this post will not be a very productive place to get answers to those questions - for one, there's a 600 character maximum for comments, which limits the efficacy of long explanations. If you are truly interested in learning the answers to those questions, it would be much more productive for you to deal with your issues elsewhere instead of derailing this comment thread.

Comment: @uniquesolution: you should read the tags on a question before you dive in and demand definitions for standard terminology in a subject that you are not familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take it apart bit by bit:

> By saying $\mu_n$ is isomorphic to the $n$th roots of unity in $k^*$, does it actually mean the $\overline{k}$-points of $\mu_n$?

No. The $k$-points of $\mu_n$ are exactly the $n^{th}$ roots of unity inside $k$: these are the solutions over $k$ of the equation $T^n-1$. $\overline{k}$-points can include more stuff: think about the example when $k=\Bbb Q$ and $n=4$. The $k$-points are $\{-1,1\}$ and the $\overline{k}$-points are $\{1,-1,i,-1\}$ (under suitable identifications).

> And it that is true, it seems like the $\overline{k}$ points should be the same thing when $n = p^m$? What makes the $k = p^m$ case more complicated?

The problem here is that in characteristic $p$, we have $T^{p^m}-1=(T-1)^{p^m}$. So there is only one point in this group scheme, and it's not reduced. So, in particular, it's not just the trivial group scheme (which is what you would expect if you only looked at the set of $p^m$th roots of unity).

Comment: By "trivial group scheme" do you mean the constant group scheme?

Comment: @EmilyWilliams yes, I mean the constant trivial group scheme.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!